# Deserializing SlugRelatedField on ForeignKey with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, serialization, frameworks

I am struggling to set a PrimaryKeyRelatedField using a SlugRelatedField.

My models.py looks like:

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    iata = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    <other unrelated fields>

class Flight(models.Model):
    flight_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, unique=True)
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport, related_name='origin', null=True)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Airport, related_name='destination', null=True)
    scheduled_departure = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    scheduled_arrival = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

My view looks like:

```
class FlightList(APIView):
    # List all flights, or create a new flight
    queryset = Flight.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FlightSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        flights = Flight.objects.all()
        serializer = FlightSerializer(flights, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = FlightSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print serializer.validated_data
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If I set my serializers.py to:

```
class FlightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = ('flight_number', 'origin', 'destination', 'scheduled_departure', 'scheduled_arrival')
```

From the shell I see the serializer renders to:

```
FlightSerializer():
    flight_number = CharField(max_length=25, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Flight.objects.all())>])
    origin = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=Airport.objects.all(), required=False)
    destination = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=Airport.objects.all(), required=False)
    scheduled_departure = DateTimeField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    scheduled_arrival = DateTimeField(allow_null=True, required=False)
```

I am able to POST origin and destination pk's that match up with Airport entries in the database to create new flights. Great.

However, I actually need to post the airport code, (i.e.) LAX as the origin or destination, and have DRF figure out the appropriate instance.

I think the way to do this is using SlugRelatedField. Despite best efforts, I'm unable to set this up properly.

I am trying to set serializers.py like this:

```
class FlightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    origin = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='iata',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = ('flight_number', 'origin', 'destination', 'scheduled_departure', 'scheduled_arrival')
```

When I pass up a valid airport code (iata) like KMS as the origin it seems to get ignored.

Is this what SlugRelatedField is supposed to be used for?

What am I doing wrong to allow my POST to send up a string, have DRF look at a field for matching db entries and store that as beautifully as it does when I simply pass up a valid PK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from a colleague on this.

The problem was I was just misconfiguration of SlugRelatedField.  To get at the airport codes, I needed to use a queryset and set the slug_field. That's all:

```
class FlightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

origin = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    slug_field='iata',
    queryset=Airport.objects.all()
)
class Meta:
    model = Flight
    fields = ('flight_number', 'origin', 'destination', 'scheduled_departure', 'scheduled_arrival')
```